# How to update book status in database when using ultrasonic sensor

Tags: php, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have this full system that reads a vehicle or an object using ultrasonic sensor and ESP8266 NodeMCU module. The program is fully working, I wan't to display a `book` status when the status of the database if `book`. But every time the code in my arduino code doesn't detect any vehicle it says it is available. It doesn't seem to go to the if else condition in the arduino code which is the status1 is equal to book.

This is where the condition for status, every time the sensor detects an object it will update the status of the database to `occu` and `avail` if there's no vehicle. I've tried this code in else if `else if(status1=="Book"`)`this should update the`status1`to book already. But why is it ending in the else condition where`status` is equal to avail?

```
if ((sensor < 10) && (sensor2 < 10)) 
 { 
    sensor = 1; 
    status1 = "Occu";
    digitalWrite(LEDRED,LOW);
    digitalWrite(LEDGREEN,HIGH);
 }
 else if (status1 == "Book") {
   sensor = 0;
    status1 ="Book";
 }
 else  
 { 
    sensor = 0;
    status1 ="Avail";
    digitalWrite(LEDGREEN,LOW);
    digitalWrite(LEDRED,HIGH);
 }
```

I don't know why, the status of the database is always updating to `avail` even though I this condition above:

```
else if (status1 == "Book") {
       sensor = 0;
        status1 ="Book";
     }
```

// I'm connecting the NodeMCU using that wifi access and it is fully working my only concern is the `status1` not updating to database which is `book`.

**Full ARDUINO CODE**

```
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h> 
#define TRIGGER 5
#define ECHO  4
#define TRIGGER2 13
#define ECHO2 15
#define LEDRED 14 
#define LEDGREEN 12 

const char* ssid = "sample";
const char* password ="sample"; 

const char* host ="192.168.254.77";

String status1;
//String parking_lot;
 long sensor;
 long sensor2;
void setup(){ 
 pinMode(LEDRED,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LEDGREEN,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
 pinMode(sensor2, INPUT);
 delay(1000);
 pinMode(TRIGGER, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(ECHO, INPUT); 
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10); 
  pinMode(TRIGGER2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(ECHO2, INPUT); 
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid); 

  WiFi.begin(ssid,password); 

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
  } 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("wifi connected");
  Serial.println("ip address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void loop() {

  long duration;
  long duration2;
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER, LOW);  
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
   digitalWrite(TRIGGER2, LOW);  
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
   digitalWrite(TRIGGER2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 

  digitalWrite(TRIGGER, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(ECHO, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER2, LOW);
  duration2 = pulseIn(ECHO2, HIGH);
  sensor = ((duration/2) / (29.1));
  sensor2 = ((duration2/2) / (29.1));

 if ((sensor < 10) && (sensor2 < 10)) 
 { 
    sensor = 1; 
    status1 = "Occu";
    digitalWrite(LEDRED,LOW);
    digitalWrite(LEDGREEN,HIGH);
 }
 else if (status1 == "Book") {
   sensor = 0;
    status1 ="Book";
 }
 else  
 { 
    sensor = 0;
    status1 ="Avail";
    digitalWrite(LEDGREEN,LOW);
    digitalWrite(LEDRED,HIGH);
 }

  Serial.println("connecting to");
  Serial.println(host); 

  WiFiClient client; 
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if(!client.connect(host,httpPort)){
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  String url = "/sampleparking/sampleparking.php?parking_lot=S1&";
         url += "status=";
         url += status1; 

   Serial.println("Requesting URL");
   Serial.println(url);

  //-------------request send to server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +  "connection: close\r\n\r\n");

  unsigned long timeout = millis(); 
  while (client.available()== 0){
    if(millis() - timeout > 5000){
      Serial.println("CLIENT TIMEOUT");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  } 
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }
  Serial.println();


  delay(10000);
  }
```

Sample parking php is where the query started for updating and displaying all the parking slots in the area.

This here is where I get the status of the parking lot:

```
$status = (isset($_GET['status']) ? strip_tags($_GET['status']) : '');
```

**sampleparking.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include "includes/connection.php";

// get the data from arduino uno and pass it to server
$status = (isset($_GET['status']) ? strip_tags($_GET['status']) : '');
$parking_lot = (isset($_GET['parking_lot']) ? strip_tags($_GET['parking_lot']) : '');

  // update status once there is vehicle detected
  $sql = $connection->prepare("UPDATE samplepark SET status = '$status' WHERE parkname ='$parking_lot'");
  $sql-> execute();

  $sql = $connection->prepare('SELECT parkid, parkname, status FROM samplepark');
  $sql->execute(); // execute query
  $result = $sql->get_result(); // fetch result

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<tr><th>Parking Slots</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $bookparking = $row["status"] == 'Avail' ? "<a class='bookparking' href='bookparkingslot.php?did=".$row['parkid']."'>Book</a>" : "";

      echo "<tr><td>" .$row["parkname"]. "</td><td>" .$row["status"]. "</td><td>" .$bookparking. "</td></tr>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Load `sampleparking.php` in id `displayparking` using ajax

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="usercontainer">
    <div class="floors">
      <div class="contentparkingslots">
        <table class="viewparkingslots" id="displayparking">
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

AJAX LOader

**ajax.js**

```
// View Users
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "sampleparking.php",
            data: $('#displayparking').serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#displayparking").html(response);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (status1 == "Book") {
    sensor = 0;
    status1 ="Book";
}
```

Logic-wise your code doesn't make sense.

You only assign `"Book"` to `status1` if it already equals `"Book"`.

Comment: I just only found out that arduino code can only send data to the server and can not retrieve any value from the server. The conditioning statement should be in the sampleparking.php. Any idea or help with this one sir?

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano find a tutorial on how to exchange data between an Arduino and a webserver. there are plenty online. break your problem down into sub problems and implement each step on it's own. then put the working bits together.